# How can we create pyspark dataframe from a multidict

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

dict = {11: {101, 102}, 22: {111, 112, 101}, 33: {101}, 44: {102}}

desired output: using spark transformation

```
-------+-------+
|user_id|team_id|
+-------+-------+
|     11|    101|
|     11|    102|
|     22|    111|
|     22|    112|
|     22|    101|
|     33|    101|
|     44|    102|
+-------+-------+
```

and later I also want to save this structure to different DB.

Comment: how the dicts are saved, can these be loaded into the memory? or they are just saved as Strings in one or more big files?

Comment: @jxc Dictionary needs to be transformed to DF, then to be saved in SQL style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to convert your **dict to a list of lists**, and then `explode` your `team_id` column in spark.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df=spark.createDataFrame([[x,list(y)] for x,y in dict.items()],['user_id','team_id'])

df.select("user_id", F.explode("team_id").alias("team_id")).show()

+-------+-------+
|user_id|team_id|
+-------+-------+
|     11|    101|
|     11|    102|
|     22|    112|
|     22|    101|
|     22|    111|
|     33|    101|
|     44|    102|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a Pandas dataframe first and then transform it into a Spark dataframe:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict.items(), columns = ['user_id', 'team_id'])
df['team_id'] = df.apply(lambda r: list(r['team_id']), axis=1)
df = df.explode('team_id')
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_df.show()
type(spark_df)
```

prints

```
+-------+-------+
|user_id|team_id|
+-------+-------+
|     11|    101|
|     11|    102|
|     22|    112|
|     22|    101|
|     22|    111|
|     33|    101|
|     44|    102|
+-------+-------+

pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

Comment: I did the same workaround, but your help is highly appreciated. Anyways, I thought If there was any spark way to achieve this.